# How to change the location of current working directory to S3 bucket location while using python on AWS?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

1. I want to change my current working directory location to the location of S3 bucket on AWS.
2. And after changing the current working directory to S3 bucket location, I want to store my code in that
   S3 bucket in .ipynb format so that i can reuse that in other codes.

I am doing that on local by `os.chdir` to change the current working directory and then I am saving my codes in that and then I am including them in other codes by using `%run "codename.ipynb"`

But not sure how to do that on AWS.

Comment: read up on https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html.  Ensure you have the appropriate credentials and permissions and then use upload_fileobj() or upload_file() depending on how you approach it.

Comment: Where is your code running? Is it on your own computer, or an Amazon EC2 instance, or a SageMaker Notebook, or somewhere else?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it is running on Jupyter notebook after creating an Amazon EC2 instance

Comment: @JohnRotenstein locally on my computer it is easy to change directory and we can save our other codes (jupyter notebooks) on that directory and then can include that code in other codes as well using %run "notebookname.ipynb" but how this can be done on AWS

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance is just like any other computer. It runs the same operating system and programs as any other computer. Thus, the ability to use S3 would be the same from an Amazon EC2 instance as from your own computer. Amazon S3 is a storage service, but it is not a "disk". I suggest doing some web searches for "jupyter notebook s3". For me, it returned articles like this: [Interacting with AWS S3 using Python in a Jupyter notebook – Carolyn Langen](http://carolynlangen.com/2017/11/22/interacting-with-aws-s3-using-python-in-a-jupyter-notebook/)